# c++ namespace best practice dilemma

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm finding that what I've considered "best practice" for use namespace in c++ is hurting the readability of my code, and making me question how to use them well.

My program consists of a few different modules which are mostly built into libraries that the "main" application uses. Each library uses it's own namespace, and their namespaces are all "inside" a project namespace to help project against name conflicts with 3rd party code. So I end up with class names such as "myproject::logging::Logger" and "myproject::reporting::ReportType" (As made up examples).

So far so good. And in my .cpp files I have no problem. I use "using myproject::logging" at the top for example, and can cleanly refer to my Logging class. In the unlikely event of a conflict between two of my namespaces I can just explicitly say which one I want. This works well.

Header files are different though. It's considered bad practice to put using statements into header files as they will affect unrelated code that may not expect them. So I always fully qualify all the names in .hpp files. That was somewhat ugly but managable up to now so I've put up with it. But now I'm increasing using template code in my libraries which means that there is *much more* actual code in my .hpp files now. And having to fully qualify every name is making the code practically unreadable due to the length of type names.

I'm starting to feel that the benefits of namespaces and best practice for using them are beginning to be outweighed by the unreadablilty of the code I'm having to write. I'm starting to wonder if I would be better abandoning the use of namespaces to gain the benefit of more readable code and fixing any name conflicts if and when they appear.

An alternative is to use short, single layer namespaces so instead of "myproject::logging::Logger" I would merely have "log::Logger" which would help a lot but make the likelyhood of namespace conflicts much higher, and also have the namespaces convey less useful information.

As I've said, this only really affects code in .hpp files as I'm happily using "using namespace" in my implementation files to make this manageable, but it *is* becoming a problem as I look at my templated code in .hpp files now and think "eww...." which can't be good :P

Anyone got any practical advice?

Comment: `using` directives are scoped, so perhaps you could make some namespace shorthands that don't leak outside the header file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have been in this situation before. It is often the case that a lot of template functions/classes in your headers are really "implementation", although by the nature of templates in C++ you are forced to put them in a header file. Thus, I just put everything in some "detail" or "implementation" namespace, where I can comfortably use "using namespace". At the end, I "drop" what people should use to the corresponding place. Like this:

```
namespace myproject { namespace somemodule {

namespace _implementation {

using namespace myproject::othermodule;
using namespace myproject::yetanothermodule;

template <...>
class some_internal_metafunction{
...
};

template <...>
class stuff_people_should_use_outside {
...
};

} // namespace implementation       

using stuff_people_should_use_outside ;
}} // namespace myproject::somemodule
```

This approach might enlarge a bit the names on your compiler reports, though.

Alternatively, you can give up the modules namespaces. But it might not be a good idea for an extremely large project.

Comment: Does it need to be `using _implementation::stuff_people_should_use_outside;`?

Comment: @dsign: You should consider updating your answer!

Comment: I'm commenting on this because of the Godot engine. Godot has pulled out into the lead as the best open-source game engine 2018, but they do not use namespaces... which is almost a dealbreaker because I'm trying to integrate into their SDK but I have to rename things... but at the same time maybe an SDK should be designed to lay over a game engine to not repeat code. What's y'all thoughts on not using namespaces in modern C++?

Answer (score 29):

Here's what I do.

In `<mylibrary.h>`:

```
namespace myproject {
  namespace mylibrary
  {
    namespace impl
    {
      using namespace otherlibrary;
      using namespace boost;
      using namespace std;
      using namespace whatever::floats::your::boat;

      class myclass;
      class myotherclass;
    };
    using impl::myclass;
    using impl::myotherclass;
  };
};
```

In the source:

```
#include <mylibrary.h>
using namespace myproject::mylibrary; //clean!
```

Comment: This seams like a good solution. I don't understand the number of lines comment/joke by Maxim.

Comment: I see. you get 2x the lines for function prototypes. One for the prototype of a function, and the other for "using impl::function" :(. It's good for classes though

Answer (score 5):

Personally? I'd get rid of the "myproject" part. What is the chance that your library will use the exact same namespace name as another *and* have a symbol defined with the same name as another?

Also, I would suggest shorter names for namespaces you expect to be used in headers.

Comment: "What is the chance that your library will use the exact same namespace name as another and have a symbol defined with the same name as another" for the given example, `logging::Logger`, I'd say the chance is quite high that there are two of those in the world. Anyone trying to use both libraries in one program is less likely, but on probabilities `::myproject::Logger` is somewhat safer than `::logging::Logger` (assuming "myproject" is replaced with the actual name of the project, ofc).

Answer (score 3):

My experience have been that it is much more convenient to have one namespace for all your code for the reasons you mentioned in your original post. This namespace protects your identifiers from clashing with identifiers from 3rd-party libraries. Your namespace is your dominion and it is easy to keep it name-conflict-free.

Comment: "Your namespace is your dominion" - if you name it with a GUID or something. Unique, memorable, and short: pick two ;-)

Comment: Memorable is not necessary, you can always look it up. So, unique and short.

Comment: So you end up calling your top-level namespace `hFPu9_`. In practice there's not much of a problem here, but in principle two unrelated projects could choose the same top-level namespace, and then you have trouble. That's why Java uses reverse domain names. It provides uniqueness at the cost of brevity.

Comment: I could use such a name: hF followed [<alt> + /] in emacs to autocomplete makes it easy to type. On practise though, I haven't seen a namespace name clash as of yet.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following to get rid of enormous amounts of `std::` in header file:

```
// mylibrary.h
namespace myproject {
  namespace mylibrary {
    namespace impl {

      using namespace std;

      namespace stripped_std {

        // Here goes normal structure of your program:
        // classes, nested namespaces etc.
        class myclass;
        namespace my_inner_namespace {
                ...     
        }

       } // namespace stripped_std   
    } // namespace impl

  using namespace impl::stripped_std;

  } // namespace mylibrary
} namespace myproject


// Usage in .cpp file
#include <mylibrary.h>
using namespace myproject::mylibrary;
```

It is similar to what was suggested by n.m., but with a modification:
there is one more auxiliary namespace `stripped_std`. 
The overall effect is that line `using namespace myproject::mylibrary;` allows you to refer to the inner namespace structure, and at the same time it does not bring `namespace std` into library user's scope.

---

It's a pity though that the following syntax

```
using namespace std {
...
}
```

is not valid in C++ at the time when this post is written.

Answer (score 0):

If your project isn't very very very huge (I mean, very huge), using only myproject should be sufficent. If you really want to divide your project into parts, you can use more generalized namespaces. For example, if I was building a game engine, I would go for namespaces like MyEngine::Core, MyEngine::Renderer, MyEngine::Input, MyEngine::Sound etc.

Comment: It's not just the *size* of the project - it's the volatility of the code, tightness of release cycles, the likelihood of similar functional requirements / entities etc., and the extent of coordination that's practical between the developers.  For example, largely independent developers (say in different countries) with tight release cycles writing lots of new code to do similar things (e.g. different pricing formulas for securities) would be more likely to want independent namespaces than a single developer predominantly tweaking implementation of existing functions....