# C++ in Visual Studio 2013 - <Class> is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header-files

I'm very new to C++/VS and might missing something in the code/configuration of my project.
In my solution I have 2 projects:

- first is NTL which I downloaded from https://bitbucket.org/ben_key/ntl, and compiled to a static library NTL.lib.
- a 'test' project in which: (1) I added the header files by specifying their directory in the properties->C++->Additional Include Files, (2) in the properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies I added "NTL.lib" (3)copied the NTL.lib file to be in the same directory as the main cpp file of the 'test' project.

My cpp only contains:

```
#include <NTL/GF2X.h>
int main() {
    GF2X P;
    return 1;
}
```

The build gives the output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(388,5): warning MSB8028: The intermediate directory (Release\) contains files shared from another project (ntl-test.vcxproj).  This can lead to incorrect clean and rebuild behavior.
1>  QuickTest.cpp
1>..\tests\QuickTest.cpp(43): warning C4101: 'n' : unreferenced local variable
1>D:\studies\Thesis\NTL-Ben-Key\Include\NTL/vector.h(79): warning C4291: 'void *operator new(size_t,_ntl_vector_placement)' : no matching operator delete found; memory will not be freed if initialization throws an exception
1>          D:\studies\Thesis\NTL-Ben-Key\Include\NTL/vector.h(36) : see declaration of 'operator new'
1>          D:\studies\Thesis\NTL-Ben-Key\Include\NTL/vector.h(319) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void NTL::BlockConstruct<T>(T *,long)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=NTL::zz_p
1>          ]
1>          D:\studies\Thesis\NTL-Ben-Key\Include\NTL/vector.h(291) : while compiling class template member function 'void NTL::Vec<NTL::zz_p>::DoSetLength(long)'
1>          D:\studies\Thesis\NTL-Ben-Key\Include\NTL/vector.h(115) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void NTL::Vec<NTL::zz_p>::DoSetLength(long)' being compiled
1>          D:\studies\Thesis\NTL-Ben-Key\Include\NTL/vec_lzz_p.h(14) : see reference to class template instantiation 'NTL::Vec<NTL::zz_p>' being compiled
1>  MyTest.cpp
1>MyTest.cpp(4): error C2065: 'GF2X' : undeclared identifier
1>MyTest.cpp(4): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'P'
1>MyTest.cpp(4): error C2065: 'P' : undeclared identifier
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It is really a simple thing and I didn't figured out what I'm missing.

Comment: that header starts with `NTL_OPEN_NNS` which is a macro that likely expands to `namespace NTL{` or so. Hence you need to use NTL::GF2X; apart from that maybe file a bug report for that warning about missing operator delete. If the compiler diagnostic is correct that could cause memory leaks or worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From  NTL/include/NTL/ tools.h:

```
#define NTL_NAMESPACE NTL
#define NTL_OPEN_NNS namespace NTL_NAMESPACE {
#define NTL_CLOSE_NNS  }
```

So when the preprocessor encounters `NTL_OPEN_NNS`, as is the case in the include file GF2X.h, it expands it to `namespace NTL` meaning the GF2X class is declared insided the namespace NTL. In order to use it you need to fully qualify it as `NTL::GF2X` or use `using namespace NTL` for discussion about which one look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281214/using-fully-qualified-names-in-c) for example.
Likewise at the end of GF2X.h there is a closing bracket after expanding NTL_CLOSE_NNS